# Bring navbar in front of the UISearchController, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I used a navBar which is created programmatically with an  UISearchController. 
 
When I start editing the UISearchBar: 
  
- the navBar stays behind the dim view
- the tableView hides half of the navbar 
- when the tabeView appeared, the cancel buttons are not selectable.

My UISearchController :

```
   let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchTableViewController") as!  SearchTableViewController
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
    resultSearchController.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    locationSearchTable.delegate = self

    let searchBar = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    searchBar.barStyle = .Default
    searchBar.translucent = true
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named:"search"), forSearchBarIcon: .Search, state : .Normal)
    searchBar.delegate=self
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

My navBar :

```
let newNavBar : UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 64.0))

func styleNavBar (){

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)


    let newItem : UINavigationItem = UINavigationItem.init()
    newItem.titleView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

    newNavBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 243/255, green: 242/255, blue: 238/255, alpha: 1.0)
        newNavBar.translucent = false
        if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 16.0) {
            let navBarAttributesDictionary : [String : AnyObject]? = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 0.51),
                NSFontAttributeName: font
            ]
            newNavBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
        }

    newNavBar.setItems([newItem], animated: false)

    self.view.addSubview(newNavBar)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(newNavBar)
}
```

[image]

How can I fix it, please?
Thanks!

Comment: show more code where you created them would be good

Comment: @Tj3n I updated my post! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this :

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use stackview for it . select search and tableview and click on stackview and constraint stackview from top/left/right/bottom

[image]

Comment: ok . you can create stackview object and instead add newNavBar into stackview and locationSearchTable.